# Text seems horrible and jagged only if using extra TV monitor as "extended"

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have connected my Full HD Philips 42" TV to my laptop via HDMI cable. When I use it as a mirror screen, no problem, everything is perfect. However if I use it as an "extended" screen, the text seems jagged, horrible (like typewriter out) like you think you adjusted your PC for performance only (right-click computer -> properties -> advanced -> adjust my computer for best performance) But, I didn't.

PS: CLeartype thing, yes I have tried. Change frequency to 60Hz... tried also. Nothing worked so far.

Any idea to solve?

Comment: are you sure its set to the proper resolution?

Comment: @Keltari yes. I also tried other options too.